# How load specific file by path?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have application and I want to add button that load specific file by my path file.
but I didn't success to get the specific file.
I try this code:

The button:

````
<b-button variant="outline-primary" @click="loadConfig(file)">Load default configuration</b-button>

file: new File([new Blob()], "253.01.00.00.SD.json", {
        type: "application/json"
      }```
````

Comment: I have clue and i want to give help that solve specific problem by your question. but i didnt success to give you help :(

Answer (score 0):

U can use fetch for that

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  ....
  methods: {
    loadConfig(file) {
      fetch('253.01.00.00.SD.json') //or fetch(file) if you want to fetch the given file
        .then(function(response) {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(myJson) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
        });
    }
 }
 ....
```

Comment: not sure if thats what you mean: ur question is not 100% clear to me

Comment: I didn't know how get the file.

Comment: file: new File([new Blob()], "253.01.00.00.SD.json", {
        type: "application/json"
      }``` it is not work well\

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `253.01.00.00.SD.json` is some file on your local directory.

```
import json from './253.01.00.00.SD.json'

export default{
  data(){
    return{
      ourData: json
    }
  }
 }
```

In the template you do something like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="data in ourData">{{data}}</div>
  </div>
</template>
```